# Styled component not overriding default styles for antd components

Tags: antd, styled-components

I have been applying a custom theme to several antd components and they have gone and worked fine. When working on the several past few components (datepicker and modal) the overridden styles are not applying.

When inspecting I am seeing this class style that is being applied and my custom style refuses to override it. Any suggestions or tips to bypass this issue?

[image]

The picture above shoes the issue. The style applied in .ant-modal-title is being overwritten. I am unsure what it means by ".css-dev-only-do-not-override-sk7ap8"? Does this indicate this class can NOT be overridden?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `styled-components`, you can override default styled by using this approach:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from 'antd';

const ButtonWrapper = styled(Button)`
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.fontSizeBase};
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 17px;
  &.ant-btn-default {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    &:not(:disabled):not(.ant-btn-disabled):hover {
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
      border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    }
  }
  &.ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
    border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    &:not(:disabled):not(.ant-btn-disabled):hover {
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
      border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    }
  }
  &.ant-btn-link {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    &:not(:disabled):not(.ant-btn-disabled):hover {
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primaryColor};
    }
  }
`;

export default ButtonWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ConfigProvider` described in: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Comment: That was my first approach. The only issue was it didn't provide FULL customization of the style. Only what they wanted to make available to customize. I am unsure it it has been changed or improved as Antd v5 was fairly new at the time.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I researched issues on GitHub and found https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/38825 and https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/38975.

There is one possible solution but it isn't a good solution - using `!important`.